# Hi, This is a php login function,how can i return a json Object like this e.g [[{“UserID”:”1”, “FullName”:”Tom”}]]

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
<?php

     include 'config.php';

     // Check whether username or password is set from android  
     if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
     {
          // Innitialize Variable
          $result='';
          $email = $_POST['username'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];

          // Query database and select the UserID and name
          $sql = 'SELECT UserID , FullName FROM Users WHERE  email = :email AND password = :password';
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->execute();
          if($stmt->rowCount())
          {


             $result = mysql_query($sql);
             $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

             if ($num_rows > 0)
            {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                  $UserID = $row['UserID'];
                  $FullName = $row['FullName'];

                  return "UserID:" . $UserID . ' ' . "FullName:" . $FullName; 
                }
            }

          }  
          elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
          {
                $result="false";
          }

          // send result back to android
          echo $result;
    }

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

Easily enough. First declare an empty array at the beginning :

```
$ar = array();
```

Then get your mysql result rows into that array (replacing your current while loop with this one):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $ar[] = $row;
}
```

then `echo` that array at the end of your code, passing it though `json_encode()` :

```
echo json_encode($ar);
```

That's about it.

Comment: yw, please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.